# How to delete sensu client from web monitoring

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, sensu

Hi I am trying to delete sensu client from monitoring, I have removed the sensu pack and folder from client, still its not reflecting in web monitor, I tried curl and direct removed from the web monitoring still no go.

I have googled and tried deleting redis keys from redis-cli and still no go, the particular client is showing in web monitor, please guide me on how to delete it from monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may have a look at the documentation:
http://sensuapp.org/docs/0.11/faq#how-do-i-delete-a-client

Comment: I have checked the documentation and tried the steps still didnt work, I even tried removing the keys from redis still not working.

Comment: So whats the actual issue? Do you get a keepalive alert?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I tried re adding the client and now everything looks perfect I am able to delete as well not sure what messed the things earlier, however at times no keep alive comes up on some clients below is the out put 

  MGMT_POSTGRES_NODE_1  keepalive No keep-alive sent from client in over 120 seconds 

however the client is reachable any suggestions?

Comment: keepalive usually is related to connection issues or the sensu-client process is not running. Maybe restart the sensu client and check the client logs. Maybe its not able to reach the queue.

Comment: The documentation link is stale.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s -i -X DELETE http://<sensu-server>:4567/clients/<client-name>
```

The above will delete the  client from sensu.  This information was obtained here:  Clients API - Sensu Docs - https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-core/1.4/api/clients/

Comment: I have the same problem, the sensu server keep checking keepalive and ssh port. Simply delete entries from Uchiwa doesn't work at all.